# Flow, get records element only gets the ID and not other fields such as name

Tags: workflow, flow-builder

I am new to salesforce so please bear with me! I am trying to create a flow that is triggered when I create a new record in a custom object (properties), and then it searches another custom object (lost clients) and it will retrieve specified fields from that record and then finally it emails it to me. The flow works fine and sends me the email as desired but the problem is that it only sends me the ID of the record and no other field that I specify such as the name (text field) or any other field. Please see below to understand more:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can try with the second option `Select fields and let salesforce do the rest` and let us know the results and then we can at least rule out permissions issue. Also what is the type of `lost clients list ext space`

Answer (score 0):

@manjit5190 I have tried both of them already, the same result, it only sends me the ID and no other fields. lost clients list ext space is a record type and the object is Lost clients, I am attaching a photo.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is how you're passing data to the Send Email action.

First of all, if you want the email body to contain a bunch of fields from a bunch of records, you have to construct the body. If you have a collection of records, as you seem to do, you have to Loop over them and assign the fields you want emailed to a text variable or a text template.

In your Get Records elements, I recommend that you select 'Automatically store all fields'. That's newer, smarter technology than the old manual variable approach.

There's a new extension that you can install, discussed [here](https://unofficialsf.com/convert-record-data-into-tables-for-email-automation-with-generate-collection-report/), that may do exactly what you need. It takes a collection of records and generates an email report out of them.  For best results, also install [this improved email action.](https://unofficialsf.com/send-rich-email-with-the-new-sendhtmlemail-action/)

I also recommend you run through [these tutorials](https://unofficialsf.com/lightning-flow-tutorials/) to get a solid grounding.

Welcome to Flow. It's tougher to learn than it should be but invested effort will repay you tenfold.